# how to remove item not match in list of object list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here is my list, it's list of object and inside object there is list:
please rev

```py
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "test": [
            {
                "id__": 1
            },
            {

                "id__": 1
            },
            {

                "id__": 1
            },
            {
                "id__": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "test": [
            {

                "id__": 1
            },
            {

                "id__": 1
            },
            {

                "id__": 1
            },
            {
                "id__": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to remove matched id with one in `objecso` it can be like this :

```py
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "test": [
            {
                "id__": 1
            },
            {

                "id__": 1
            },
            {

                "id__": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "test": [

            {
                "id__": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here is what I try:
and notice that is final is the list mentioned above

```py
for i in final:
    for j in i["test"]:
        if j['id__'] == i["id"]:
            i.pop()
```

can I use some help of you kind guys, I tried with remove attribute in list, and still no result satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
filtered_result = []
for i in a:
    lst_id = i["id"]
    lst_to_compare = i["test"]
    filtered_inner_list = [item for item in lst_to_compare if item["id__"] == lst_id]
    filtered_result.append({"id": lst_id, "test": filtered_inner_list})

print(filtered_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would solve this problem, hope it helps. The problem with your solution was that you were trying to eliminate the item of a list which you were looping over, so the whole iteration was faulty.

```
ind_list = list()
for key in my_list:
    id_num = key['id']
    for item in key['test']:
        if item['id__'] != id_num:
            ind_list.append(key['test'].index(item))
    for i in ind_list:
        key['test'].pop(i)
    ind_list.clear()
print(my_list)
```